# Switching Ubuntu Version on dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

I just [found myself in times of trouble](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bcdNzMMvF_k):

I have a dual boot configuration (Ubuntu 18.10 and Windows 10)

My Ubuntu 18.10 is, as someone told me, EOL (and dead, it won't boot again) so I need to switch versions. I also need a CUDA-compatible version, so I was thinking to install Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS.

<s>I'm a noob</s> As I don't have a lot of system installation experience:

*Can I safely install the new version (18.04.2 LTS) in the partition of the old one (18.10)?*

OR

*Do I have to repeat the process of installing Linux in dual boot?* (remove the EXT4 partition, expand the windows one, reinstall the windows bootloader, then create a new partition, reinstall GRUB, install the OS etc)

Comment: Ubuntu installation should do everything for you, including formatting the partition (you don't need to do it with diskpart) and install GRUB, which scans for other OS (including windows). You should not need to do all those steps you mention.

Comment: GRUB is already there, that is what is concerning me. If i remove the older partition (the one that is currently hosting Ubuntu 18.10, should i do that? (i mean, im not removing the partition itself, only what's inside it, Ubuntu)) im afraid i remain with no bootloader at all. So, are u sure i only need to flash a USB with Ubuntu 18.04.2 and then boot from USB?

Comment: A new installation will install GRUB again, despite that is already installed or not.

Comment: Okey, thank you a lot

Comment: @guillermochamorro That's not a comment!  That's an answer!  **:-)** Please post one and leave a comment [at]Fabby and I'll come back and upvote!